# Acceleration of a massless body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, string

Let's say we have a massless body connected to 2 strings. Now lets pull the body with a force $F$. As the body is massless tension in both strings will be equal. Let that be $T$. Now we know that $$F-2T=Ma$$

But as $M=0$, we get $F=2T$. Now although the forces are equal the body still has an non zero acceleration $a$. How can this be possible, even theoretically?

Comment: I suppose $F$ should be some other forces acting on $M$??

Comment: How did you deduce that value of the acceleration $a$ is non-zero $a\neq 0$?

Comment: @Stratiev the body can have any acceleration it satisfies the equation

Comment: @Stratiev Please do not answer in comments.  Post a proper answer.  Comments cannot be properly voted on by the community nor can they be accepted as a an answer by the original question poster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newtonian mechanics: massless particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560905/newtonian-mechanics-massless-particles)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the equation doesn't tell you the acceleration is 0, doesn't mean it implies the opposite. If A doesn't imply B, that doesn't mean that not B is true. It might be that B is still true but you just can't infer it from A. In this case A is "the equation is satisfied" and B is "the acceleration is 0". The correct way of inferring that the acceleration is 0 is by knowing that massless objects always travel at the speed of light so one cannot accelerate or decelerate them. So B is indeed true, but it could not be inferred from Newton's laws, since they don't apply.

Comment: While true,  see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560905/newtonian-mechanics-massless-particles  for a discussion of "effectively zero mass" in Newtonian physics.   The problem in the posed question here is a lack of understanding of vectors

Comment: Can u please clarify me this - In Newtonian Mechanics a sting is considered to be mass less .Now,, in a simple case of  2 block of unequal masses attached to a string that passes over pulley(vertically ) isn't acceleration of string same as net acceleration of block ?but by reading your answer it shows string should move with speed of light.Please rectify me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Bhavay The mass of the string is not 0 so the argument that it will travel at the speed of light does not apply. The assumption that the string is massless is used to justify treating the center of mass of the system exactly where the attached mass is at the end. If one takes into account the mass of the string, the effective length of a pendulum would change so it is likely that the period will be different if the string has a different mass. In the case of the pulley, the assumption that the mass of the string is 0 works because we know that it will move along with the block.

Comment: We apply Newton's law not on the string, but on the whole system of block and string and consider the mass of the string to be negligible. It is an approximation, not a fact about the string.

Comment: Sir is it correct to say that in the op's question mass less particle can only be photon then.

Comment: @Bhavay Not necessarily. I'm not sure precisely what OP meant, which is why I asked in the comments. Perhaps OP is indeed talking about a type of "effectively zero mass" mentioned earlier. I wrote what I wrote, because I think that OP was incorrectly making a logical inference, where one cannot be made and that is the essence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can tell if the acceleration is 0 or not from the second law $$F-2T=Ma=0$$

The acceleration is indeed 0 but to prove it you have to use another equation that involves the acceleration or maybe the velocity $v$ separately from the mass. This second equation will then add a constraint on the values of the acceleration.

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined how you are applying the force, nor what is restraining the two strings so as to have tension occur. Force is a vector, not a magnitude. Ditto for Tension. Put in the directions of all these forces to see the answer.

Comment: Sir , actually tension is a scalar quantity.

Comment: @Bhavay  then how would you define the tension in a rubber sheet which is being pulled in the X-direction by 1N and in the Y-direction by 2N ?

Comment: That's force due to surface tension. Surface tension is again a scalar quantity.I can show it if u want. It's on the Wikipedia .